# Running Composer-installed tasks in Phing

Tags: php, composer-php, phing

I have a PHP app that is getting its dependencies installed with Composer. Composer puts the binaries in the bin folder. I want to use Phing to execute some tests on my code, but Phing isn't finding the apps installed in {basedir}/bin/.

For example, this works:

```
 <exec command="./bin/phpcs --standard=zend ." passthru="true"></exec>
```

But this fails:

```
 <phpcodesniffer standard="ZEND" />
```

The Phing error message basically says that phpcs is not installed. How do I tell Phing to run the binary from the bin directory when using the built-in task for phpcodesniffer (which has nicer outputs than the exec example above)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered my own question. I just needed to add this right above the phpcodesniffer line above:

```
<exec command="export PATH=./bin:$PATH" />
```

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone wonders, it's also possible to add Composer's autoload into Phing's autoload routine. With something like next line

```
<autoloader autoloaderpath="${project.basedir}/vendor/autoload.php"/>
```

This would allow Phing to "see" all the dependencies served with composer.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the [`includepath`](https://www.phing.info/phing/guide/en/output/hlhtml/#IncludePathTask) task to prepend (by default) a path to the include_path similar to `export PATH=./bin:$PATH`

```xml
<includepath classpath="./bin" />
```